# How to create an ssh connection Terminal shortcut with commands on Mac OS X (Yosemite)

Tags: linux, macos, mac, ssh, putty

On my Windows PC I got a Putty Batch File that connects to my Pi (SSH - Openelec), authenticates as `root`, kills a process (`hyperiond`), and starts it again. I have to use this file frequently because `hyperion` sometime gets pretty messed up (at least for me).

In Short it does the following:

```
Connect to 192...... ; 
Authenticate as root with password ; 
Run the commands: killall hyperiond ; 
and /storage/hyperion/bin/hyperiond.sh /storage/.config/hyperion.config.json
```

I would like to do the same thing with my Macbook. Is there the possibility to create such a "batch" file on Mac with terminal?

Answer (score 0):

yes, there should be `sh` and `ssh` on Mac.

- Create a file `batch.sh`
- Make it executable `chmod u+x batch.sh`

Content of file:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh root@192... "killall hyperiond; /storage/hyperion/bin/hyperiond.sh /storage/.config/hyperion.config.json"
```

And then run it as `./batch.sh`. It should prompt for the password and execute the batch. If you want to get rid of the password, set up the keys:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id root@192...
```